# Hibernate 4.3.4 use CriteriaUpdate

Tags: java, hibernate

i need a example of creating a `CriteriaUpdate` using Hibernate `4.3.2` there is not much example on the web.

i need something like

```
private void updateStudent(final Student studentToUpdate)
{       
    final CriteriaBuilder builder = ..............
    final CriteriaUpdate<Student>update = builder.createCriteriaUpdate(Student.class);
}
```

i am using regular Hibernate SessionFactory my question is... how can i get the `createCriteriaUpdate` method how i get the `CriteriaBuilder` i have seen examples creating from EntityManager but we are using regular `org.hibernate.Session`

any help is hugely appreciate.